# gspread/ httplib2 SSLHandshakeError

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, httplib2, gspread

I had gspread for python working, but after about a month I started getting the following error:

```
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
```

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gspread-0.3.0-py2.7.egg/gspread/client.py", line 331, in authorize
    client.login()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gspread-0.3.0-py2.7.egg/gspread/client.py", line 101, in login
    self.auth.refresh(http)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client-1.4.12-py2.7.egg/oauth2client/client.py", line 597, in refresh
    self._refresh(http.request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client-1.4.12-py2.7.egg/oauth2client/client.py", line 768, in _refresh
    self._do_refresh_request(http_request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client-1.4.12-py2.7.egg/oauth2client/client.py", line 799, in _do_refresh_request
    self.token_uri, method='POST', body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.8-py2.7.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1570, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.8-py2.7.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1317, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.8-py2.7.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1252, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.8-py2.7.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1044, in connect
    raise SSLHandshakeError(e)
httplib2.SSLHandshakeError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:0D0890A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_verify:unknown message digest algorithm
```

I have tried everything I can think of, including installing a new python distribution, but nothing works. I am on a mac, I have upgraded pyOpenSSL and done everything I can think of. Does anyone have an idea?